# Как массово удалить скобки в названиях файлов

Tags: shell

В папке много файлов с именами в виде цифр в круглых скобках:

```
(123).txt
(757823).txt
```

Подскажите, как массово удалить круглые скобки из названий файлов? 
Чтобы стало:

```
123.txt
757823.txt
```

Comment: Решения через GUI устроят Вас? Массовые операции с названиями файлов я проделываю с помощью многофункциональной бесплатной программы [**Bulk Rename Utility**](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php). В Вашем случае по мне так самое простое — [**сделать вот так**](http://i.imgur.com/cPRvQb6.png). Спасибо.

Comment: Если в папке есть другие файлы, а не только файлы с числами в скобках, [**тогда так**](http://i.imgur.com/SIRViDD.png). Если ещё есть дополнительные условия, внесите их в вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо мне помогла эта утилита

Answer (score 3):

Пока как то длинно получилось, но вроде безопасно с точки зрения спецсимволов:

```
find -name '(*).txt' -print | sed 's/$/\x0/;p;s/[()]//g' | tr -d '\n' | xargs -0 -n2 mv
```

**Внимание**: перед выполненем в боевом режиме выполните команду с заменой `mv` на `echo` что бы проконтролировать какие аргументы будут переданы команде mv.

В команде происходит следующее: `find` находит все подходящие файлы и печатает по одному на строку. `sed` дописывает 0-символ перед концом строки и печатет строку, после чего удаляет *все* скобки в имени и еще раз печатает строку (действие по умолчанию). После него `tr` удаляет переводы каретки.
`xargs` выполняет заданную команду передавая попарно по 2 аргумента из входного потока, разделенные 0-символом. В этом режиме xargs гарантирует правильную передачу параметров с любыми спецсимволами (пробелами и кавычками)

Comment: отвечает mv: missing file operand

Comment: а если заменить на echo , то ничего не отвечает

Comment: @Новичок Такая ошибка происходит в случае если в каталоге нет ни одного файла для переименования. _Любые_ команды пробуйте частями, сначала добиваетесь что бы find нашел именно те файлы которые надо, потом уже скармиливаете результат sed и так проверяете что выдает каждая стадия

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f1 in `find /temp -name '*'`; do
   f2=${f1/(/}
   f2=${f2/)/}
   echo "$f1 -> $f2"
   mv $f1 $f2
done
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/47706/

Comment: Отвечает:  find: ‘/temp’: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                           хотя папка temp есть

Answer (score 0):

Команда

```
$ rename 's/[\(\)]//g' *.txt
```

переименует все файлы `.txt`, удалив круглые скобки.

Comment: хм. судя по описанию rename она должна это сделать. Но на моей системе почему то не переименовывает. У вас она отрабатывает в таком виде ?

Comment: @Mike, да, отрабатывает.

Comment: Я разобрался. оказывается бывают два вида rename. одна из пакета `util-linux`, которая как раз у меня и которая так не умеет. А другая поставляется вместе с `perl` (по факту она вообще линк на исполнимый файл perl), вот она как раз понимает такой синтаксис

Comment: @Mike, всё ещё хуже: в debian помимо util-linux есть ещё пакет rename. вообще имеет смысл вызывать не rename, а более конкретно prename. тогда шансов нарваться на не ту реализацию меньше.

Comment: @Mike rename не из util-linux это небольшой perl скрипт http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=303814

Comment: @Hellseher Да, тот который с тем синтаксисом, что приведен в этом ответе - это от perl. Но на моей системе, например, утилита rename именно из пакета util-linux, а не из перла. И как заметил Баракин, есть еще третий вариант. Так что тут как повезет, в системе может оказаться один из 3х rename, только один из которых сможет работать с регуляркой

Comment: @Mike. надежней выходит писать однострочник find+sed/tr+mv.